# Angular: ¿Cómo filtrar datos por rangos de población?

Tags: angular, filtro

Tengo una tabla en la que cargo datos mediante llamada a una API. Además tengo unos filtros para poder filtrar datos. Ahora mismo tengo dos filtros, uno caja de búsqueda y un select, pero me gustaría terner uno más un poco distinto a los anteriores (ya añadido en la vista filtros html), uno en el que filtre al introducir un valor mínimo y/o máximo para filtrar por población. ¿Cómo podría hacer esto? Ya que es una búsqueda por rango y no exacta Gracias.

**Vista tablas html**

```
<tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let pais of paises |buscarRegion:buscarporRegion | searchFilter: searchTerm ">
          <td>{{ pais.region }}</td>
          <td> {{ pais.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ pais.poblacion }}</td>
    
        </tr>
        </tbody>
```

**tabla ts**

```
  paises: Paises[] = [];

  @Input() buscarporRegion = '';
  @Input() searchTerm = '';
   
 
   constructor(private paisesService: PaisesService) { }
 
   ngOnInit(): void {
 
     this.getPaises();
   }

 
   getPaises(){
     this.paisesService.getAllPaises().subscribe((response) =>{
       this.paises = response;
       console.log(response)
 
     });
   }
```

**vista filtros html**

```
<select class="form-control mx-sm-1 mb-2" [(ngModel)]="buscarporRegion">
        <option value="">Regiones</option>
        <option value="{{region.region}}" *ngFor="let region of paises">{{region.region}}</option>
      
      </select>

      <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Buscar País" [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" >

 
      <label>Buscar Población:</label><br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Min. Población" style="margin-right: 10px;" >
        <input type="text" placeholder="Max. Población" >
    

      </div>
```

**vista filtros html**

```
  @Input() paises: Paises[] = [];
  paisesFiltrados: Paises[] = [];

   buscarporRegion = '';
   searchTerm = '';
```

**pipes**

```
export class BuscarRegionPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, arg: any): any {
    const buscarporregion = [];
    for (const recorrido of value) {
      if(recorrido.region.toLowerCase().indexOf(arg.toLowerCase()) > -1){
        buscarporregion.push(recorrido);
      }
    }
    return buscarporregion;
  } 

export class SearchFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(list: any[], filterText: string): any {
    return list ? list.filter(item => item.name.search(new RegExp(filterText, 'i')) > -1) : [];
  }
}
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Angular: ¿Cómo filtrar datos por rangos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/545375/angular-c%c3%b3mo-filtrar-datos-por-rangos)

Comment: No, en esa pregunta no se da solución. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Usando un callback pipe llamamos a un método dentro del componente
> restrinjo los datos a  que estén dentro de un intervalo podes
> modificar el método para región población o enlazar la cota superior e
> inferior dinámicamente con datos de la aplicación  o lo que se te
> ocurra

[proyecto desplegado github pages](https://nestdanchia.github.io/pipe/)
En este primer caso se mostraran los países cuya población esta en el

> intervalo  cerrado

`2000000<=poblacion<=5000000`

```
ng generate pipe callback
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'callback',
  pure: false
})
export class CallbackPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any[], callback: (item: any) => boolean): any {
    if (!items || !callback) {
        return items;
    }
    return items.filter(item => callback(item));
}
  

}
en el componente

interface pais {name: string, region: string,poblacion:number}
paises: pais[] = [
    { name: 'UK', region: 'oeste', poblacion: 5000000 },
    { name: 'UK', region: 'este', poblacion: 3000000 },
    { name: 'UK', region: 'norte', poblacion: 1000000 },
    { name: 'UK', region: 'sur', poblacion: 100000000 },
    { name: 'HK', region: 'oeste', poblacion: 700000 },
    { name: 'HK', region: 'este', poblacion: 2000000 },
    { name: 'HK', region: 'norte', poblacion: 500000 },
    { name: 'HK', region: 'sur', poblacion: 4000000 },

  ];
findInterval(country: pais): any {
    return country.poblacion <=5000000 && country.poblacion >= 2000000
  }
en la vista
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let pais of paises | callback:findInterval">
    Pais:{{ pais.name }} Region:{{pais.region}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Por los comentario que haces te aclaro que el pipe callback usa a la función findInterval  en la etiqueta de la vista solo tenes que escribir `| callback(que es el nombre del pipe):findInterval (que es la función que se ejecutara)`

> Ahora con valores que se actualicen desde los dos input
> Generamos un servicio que comunicara el cambio
> BehaviorSubject es un sujeto que
> emite el último valor emitido por la fuente Observable almacena
> tanto un Observable como un Observador  permite la subscripcion
> mediante  el metodo next para enviar datos a un
> observable
> [Behavior Subject](https://recuperar-contrasena.com/angular/pequeno-ejemplo-sobre-como-usar-behaviorsubject-observable-en-angular/)

```
ng g service parametros
 //parametros.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ParametrosService {
    //le damos un valor inicial
     maxBs = new BehaviorSubject<number>(100000000);
     minBs = new BehaviorSubject<number>(500000);
  // permitimos la subscripcion a el mediante
     maxi = this.maxBs.asObservable()
     mixi = this.minBs.asObservable()
  
  constructor() { 
  // enviamos los ultimos valores
  updatedDataMax(data: number) {
    this.maxBs.next(data);
  }
  updatedDataMin(data: number) {
    this.minBs.next(data);
  }

}

En el pipe inyectamos al servicio para poder detectar al cambio de los valores de la cotas del intervalo

import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { ParametrosService } from './parametros.service';
@Pipe({
  name: 'callback',
  pure: false
})
export class CallbackPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private service:ParametrosService) {  }
  transform(items: any[], callback: (item: any,max:number,min:number) => boolean): any {
    let max:number;
    let min:number;
  this.service.maxi.subscribe((valor:number)=>max=valor);
  this.service.mixi.subscribe((valor:number)=>min=valor);
    if (!items || !callback) {
        return items;
    }
    return items.filter(item =>
      callback(item,max,min))
    }

  

  }
  El componente recibe una funcion desde el pipe con los valores de las cotas y le comunicara esos valores a la vista
   // estos valores son los iniciales del input no se detectara su cambio se detectara el cambio mediante
   // la libreria rxjs en el servicio
   max:number=0; min:number=0
   
  paises: pais[] = [
    { name: 'UK', region: 'oeste', poblacion: 5000000 },
    { name: 'UK', region: 'este', poblacion: 3000000 },
    { name: 'UK', region: 'norte', poblacion: 1000000 },
    { name: 'UK', region: 'sur', poblacion: 100000000 },
    { name: 'HK', region: 'oeste', poblacion: 700000 },
    { name: 'HK', region: 'este', poblacion: 2000000 },
    { name: 'HK', region: 'norte', poblacion: 500000 },
    { name: 'HK', region: 'sur', poblacion: 4000000 },

  ];
  constructor(private serviceParam:ParametrosService){}
   ngOnInit(): void {}
   
   
  findInterval(country: pais, max: number, min: number): any {
    console.log('findInterval', max, min)
    return country.poblacion <= max && country.poblacion >= min
  }
  cambiamax(valor:any){
    this.serviceParam.updatedDataMax(valor);
    console.log(valor)
  }
  cammbiamin(valor:any){
    this.serviceParam.updatedDataMin(valor);
     console.log('valor)
  }
```

> En la vista nos interesa el cambio mediante ngModelChange el cual nos
> permite mediante el servico
> actualizar los valores del Input que manejamos localmente en el pipe y la funcion findInterval de callback
> Asi nos mostrara inicialmente la lista entre los valores
> 100000000 y 500000 al ingresar desde los inputs a nuevos valores la lista se actualiza automaticamente ya que detecta el cambio gracias al servicio que usa a la libreria rxjs.**BehaviorSubject** puede tener un valor inicial numerico como en este caso o tambien un metodo que le retorne el valor que mas nos guste  para las cotas

```
  <input type="number" [ngModel]="max" (ngModelChange)="  cambiamax($event)" >
  <input type="number" [ngModel]=" min" (ngModelChange)="cammbiamin($event) " >
   <ul>
  <li *ngFor="let pais of paises | callback:findInterval">
    Pais:{{ pais.name }} Region:{{pais.region}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hola, una duda, pero si esos datos quiero buscarlos a través del input de máx mín? cómo enlazo ese input para que me busque los países de por ejemplo mínimo 1.000.000 habitantes y máx. 30.000.000 o la cifra que se quiera?

Comment: muy simple las cotas tendrán el valor del máximo o del mínimo  country.poblacion<=this.max && country.poblacion >= this.min ---

Comment: ¿Y en los input de máx y min tendría que poner [ngModel]=findInterval? En los otros dos filtros tengo un ngModel para que funcione. Este como es un poco distinto me tiene un poco perdida. Gracias.

Comment: [(ngModel)]=max----[(ngModel)]=min

Comment: es un enlace muy simple repasa https://academia-binaria.com/servicios-inyectables-en-Angular/

Comment: te lo aclaro en la pregunta porque al consultar si escribir  [ngModel]=findInterval  te explicare que  función cumple pipe callback y tambien en que lugar ubicarlo en la vista pero si usas muchos filtros tener en cuenta que no entren en contradicción hay que tener en claro que se quiere mostrar en la vista con los filtros en 5 lo tenes en la respuesta

Comment: Sí, el callback sé que hay que ponerlo en la vista de la tabla. Pero el componente con los filtros los tengo en otra vista (son 3 filtros, el de región que es un select y el search y ahora este de máx mín). Ahí he añadido el ngModel con máx y mín pero me da "undefined". Estoy intentando entender por qué. Gracias!

Comment: Es por la detección del cambio yo habitualmente gestiono el estado mediante  la libreria rxjs https://rafaelneto.dev/blog/gestionar-estado-angular-rxjs-behaviorsubject-servicios-datos-observables/   al iniciar la vista el valor es undefined en tu caso en el mio ya tiene valores si no conoces observables podes intentar un  *ngIf en la vista  con la condición que max and min no sean undefined https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf también los formularios reactivos son muy útiles para detectar el cambio si no los conoces podes ver https://runebook.dev/es/docs/angular/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: si no podes resolver el valor inicial de max y min dentro de la función al llamar a la función el pipe lo cual es al inicio de la aplicación mañana te subo una solucion  saludos

Comment: De momento, no lo he conseguido. Al llamar a la función aquí <li *ngFor="let pais of paises | callback:findInterval"> los datos de la tabla no me cargan. La función la puse en el componente donde carga la table` findInterval(country: Paises): any { return country.population <=this.min && country.population >= this.max }` Max y min lo inicialicé a 0 y luego en el componente.ts de los filtros puse estas dos variable con el Input para poder usarlas.

Comment: Y mi mi vista de filtros ` <input type="text" placeholder="Min. Población" [(ngModel)]="min" > <input type="text" placeholder="Max. Población" [(ngModel)]="max" >`

Comment: TE actualize la respuesta la forma en la que yo puedo detectar el cambio en los inputs es mediante la libreria rxjs si uso el pipe asi si puedo enviar los valores actualizados de los inputs a la funcion

Comment: findInterval que se un callback del pipe ya que de por si los valores de los  inputs al generarse el pipe no puede  este detectar dentro del callback a los valores del input solo puedo hacerlo mediante observables saludos

Comment: Hola, te agradezco mucho tu tiempo. Lo he aplicado pero no me carga los datos de la tabla con el callback:findInterval, ni siquiera en consola. Lo cierto es que se me hace un poco complejo para mi nivel. Realmente quizá lo mejor fuera en vez de un valor mín o máximo un input tipo range pero no he encontrado ningún ejemplo para acomodarlo. De todas formas, muchísimas gracias por haber intentado ayudarme.

Comment: mañana lo subo a github pages  así ves como funciona Si podes genera un proyecto nuevo solo para ver como aplicar lo que respondí copia  app.component.ts y  appcomponent.html crea el servicio y  pipe con el código que subí  te darás cuenta como funciona .El problema es muy interesante  el pipe no detectar el cambio requiere  de observables  hay un problema para la detección de cambio en los inputs con el pipe por la forma que angular detecta el cambio y el ciclo de vida  mi solución es con observables lee algo de observables son muy útiles para detectar el cambio buen domingo

Comment: Genial, gracias. Lo probaré y echaré un vistazo también a github cuando lo subas. Quizá el problema lo tengo porque la tabla la tengo en un componente y los filtros en otro. Estoy intentando practicar con distintos tipos de filtros, pero este se me ha puesto un poco cuesta arriba. De nuevo, gracias por tu paciencia.

Comment: si podes subi tu proyecto a github asi lo corrijo saludos

Comment: Aquí lo subí, gracias: https://github.com/basileia7/buscadorfiltros

Comment: te agrege el proyecto desplegado en github pages https://nestdanchia.github.io/pipe/     miro a ver como lo estructuraste saludos

Comment: lo miro mejor mañana pero vos llamas population y yo poblacion  es decir seria en findInterval creo debe ir  pais.population

Comment: cierto, no me di cuenta de ese importantísimo detalle. Lo he cambiado y ahora ya carga la tabla y funciona, sin embargo no funciona del todo a la idea que tenía. Por ejemplo, si le pongo el mínimo en 20.000 y el máx nada, la idea es que filtre los países cuya población tiene más de 20.000 habitantes. Si le pongo min 20.000 y max 20.000.000 que filtre los que están en ese rango. Ahora mismo si le pones por ejemplo mín 20.000 y máx 0 te saca países de población hasta 20.000. También creo que debo agregar un botón de reseteo.

Comment: Es porque la condición que puse es  es un and podes haces cuantos collback quieras con las condiciones que quieras o modificar la condicion que se me ocurrio que hace lo que decís hasta podes poner condiciones para estar dentro del  el intervalo https://www.wake-up-neo.com/es/javascript/compruebe-si-un-valor-esta-dentro-de-un-rango-de-numeros/972681526/.También no se porque denotas   @Input()  max:number= 0; si no se envió ese valor desde otro componente

Comment: El @Input lo tenía puesto de antes, como en los otros filtros me hacía falta pensaba que en este también.